# Gear of Car takes time to shift from 1st to 2nd gear

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, shifting, impala

My car is 2005 Chevy Impala. While driving in automatic mode, I have to drive at 18 MPH for around 4-5 seconds to allow the gear to shift from first to second (or second to third gear, I am not sure which gear). With a normal transmission, we can just increase speed from 0 without thinking about anything. 
What can be my problem?
What is the cheap(money) solution to my problem?

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid level in your Impala?

Comment: Can fuild level cause some problem?

Comment: If the fluid level is too low, it won't want to shift right due to lack of line pressure. It has to wait until the pressure is good enough to do it. It's just something I'd check before you get too far. But then if it if is low, you need to figure out why it's low. Ensure you're checking it with the engine/tranny fully warm, car sitting on level ground. Follow your owner's manual instructions. If it is low, DO NOT OVER FILL ... bad juju.